# Receiving TypeError: string indices must be integers

Tags: python, json, pandas

I have a JSON file in the following format:

```
'assigned_to': {
    'link': 'https://xxxx.xxxxx-xxxxx.com/api/now/table/xxxxxx/b3c9d420dbafcf00ea3', 
    'value': 'b3c9d420dbafcf00ea3'
}
```

When trying to access 'value' using the following code

```
m = [x['value'] for x in df['assigned_to'].tolist()]

df['assigned_code'] = pd.Series(m).values
df = df.drop(columns=['assigned_to'])
```

I am getting the following error:

```
m = [x['value'] for x in df['assigned_to'].tolist()]
TypeError: string indices must be integers
```

Comment: You can directly do `df[col] = [....]` without the extra pd.Series step.

Comment: Can you post a sample of `df['assigned_to']` ?

Comment: why not just write x['assigned_to']['value']

Comment: @coldspeed that would work except that I'm doing the same for another nested 'value' coming from a different parent.  This is why I'm defining m to retrieve the 'value' from the specific 'assigned_to' parent.